# Can't find out how to transform Tango Point Cloud

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, java-me, tango

I work with the Google Tango right now and so far everything worked fine, but I stumbled upon a few strange things.

There is a class ScenePoseCalculator in the Tango Examples. And there is a method "toOpenGlCameraPose". When using this, the OpenGL camera however is not set up correctly. When I move forward, the camera moves backwards. Left and right are swapped as well.

But the most difficult thing is to transform the PointCloud correctly. I do the following:

Create an Vector3-Array:

```
Vector3f [] vertices = new Vector3f[mPointCloud.getGeometry().getVertices().capacity()];
    for(int i=0; i<mPointCloud.getGeometry().getVertices().capacity(); i++) {
        vertices[i] = new Vector3f(
            mPointCloud.getGeometry().getVertices().get(i*3), 
            mPointCloud.getGeometry().getVertices().get(i*3+1),
            mPointCloud.getGeometry().getVertices().get(i*3+2));
    }
```

In the PointCloud Callback of the TangoListener I do:

```
private void updateXYZIJ() {

    try {
        if(pcm.getLatestXyzIj().xyzCount<10) return;

        TangoCoordinateFramePair fp = new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE,
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE);

        TangoXyzIjData xyzIj = pcm.getLatestXyzIj();
        depthArray = new float[xyzIj.xyzCount * 3];
        xyzIj.xyz.get(depthArray);

        com.projecttango.rajawali.Pose p = 
            ScenePoseCalculator.toDepthCameraOpenGlPose(
                tangoProvider.getTango().getPoseAtTime( 
                    xyzIj.timestamp, fp), this.setupExtrinsics());

        Pose cloudPose = this.rajawaliPoseToJMEPoseCLOUD(p);

        currentPointCloudData = new PointCloudUpdate(
            new Date(),
            depthArray,
            xyzIj.xyzCount,
            xyzIj.ijRows,
            xyzIj.ijCols,
            0,
            cloudPose,
            null
        );

        // inform listeners
        for (PointCloudListener listener : this.pointsListeners) {
            listener.acceptMessage(tangoProvider, this.currentPointCloudData);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To transform the PointCloud I do:

```
this.transformation = new Matrix4f();
    this.transformation.setRotationQuaternion(
        this.referencePose.orientation);
    this.transformation.setTranslation(this.referencePose.place);

absVertices = new Vector3f[vertices.length];
    for(int i=0; i<vertices.length; i++) {

        // Create new Vertex
        absVertices[i]=new Vector3f(
            vertices[i].x,
            vertices[i].y,
            vertices[i].z
        );

        Vector3f v = absVertices[i];

        transformation.rotateVect(absVertices[i]);
        transformation.translateVect(absVertices[i]);
    }
```

But whatever I do. I've tried everything. But it won't look right. The PointClouds get stapled over each other or look like they where placed without any sense.

Hope someone knows more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone still looking to find out how to do this, I just managed it in jMOnkeyEngine3. The secret is, one has to use the INVERSE of the rotation Quaternion which the Tango delivers.

Okay, here is how it works:

Getting depth data with the Callback:

```
public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj)
```

Create an Array of vertices from the xyz-Array:

```
// Create new array, big enough to hold all vertices
        depthArray = new float[xyzIj.xyzCount * 3];
        xyzIj.xyz.get(depthArray);

        // Create Vertices
        Vector3f[] vertices = new Vector3f[xyzIj.xyzCount];
        for(int i=0; i<xyzIj.xyzCount; i++) {
            vertices[i] = new Vector3f(
                depthArray[i*3],
                depthArray[i*3+1], 
                depthArray[i*3+2]);
        }
```

Use the ScenePoseCalculator from Rajawali3d:

```
com.projecttango.rajawali.Pose p = ScenePoseCalculator
            .toDepthCameraOpenGlPose(tangoProvider.getTango().getPoseAtTime( 
                  xyzIj.timestamp, framePair_SS_D), this.setupExtrinsics());
```

Device intrinsics must be ordered before that, but remember to do it in an TRY/CATCH enclosure.

After that, get Rotation Quaternion and Pose Vector3 from the Tango Pose:

```
Pose cloudPose = this.rajawaliPoseToJMEPoseCLOUD(p);
```

That method is defined here:

```
private Pose rajawaliPoseToJMEPoseCLOUD(com.projecttango.rajawali.Pose p) {
    Pose pose = new Pose(
        new Vector3f(
            (float)p.getPosition().x, 
            (float)p.getPosition().y, 
            (float)p.getPosition().z),
        new Quaternion(
            (float)p.getOrientation().x,
            (float)p.getOrientation().y,
            (float)p.getOrientation().z,
            (float)p.getOrientation().w
        ));

    return pose;
}
```

Then Put the vertices in a node and transform that node with the Pose Data of the according XYZIJ-Data:

```
meshNode.setLocalRotation(pcu.referencePose.orientation.inverse());
    meshNode.setLocalTranslation(pcu.referencePose.place);
```

Hope it helps someone. Took me 4 days to figure it out x(

Cheers